# htaccess should redirect from non-www to www, from http to https, and internaly use content from www subfolder. But still returns error 500

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

my htaccess should solve these tasks:

1. redirect all url from http to https
2. redirect all url from non-www to www domain name
3. internaly load all content from www folder (without redirection)

here is my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite\.cz$
RewriteRule (.*) https://www.mysite.cz/$1 [R=301, L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.cz$
RewriteRule ^$ www/
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.cz$
RewriteRule (.*) www/$1
```

but this returns error 500, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2):

This should do it (I thought a rewrite was better and it avoids redirecting some requests twice, which is not desirable):

```
RewrieEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.example.com [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,END]

RewrieCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/www
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ www/$1
```

You might also want to consider a 301 redirect for any requests to a URL starting `/www/` to remove it. Let me know and I can update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

For the last rule have a negative lookahead to avoid You can also refactor to avoid multiple redirects.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.cz$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^((?!www/).*)$ www/$1 [L,NC]
```